# Get Google Drive video stream in json

Tags: json, google-drive-api

I know this question has been answered a lot, I have a script that get the download links for a google drive video, it works well but the links are not working. I've seen an app that has this function working and the output of it is:

```
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?api=GameLife&id=a4f79817c6ef67f8&itag=59&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&ttl=transient&mm=30&mn=sn-n4v7kne7&ms=nxu&mv=u&pl=33&sc=yes&ei=sR8jWbqLHoGbqwX595ioDw&driveid=0B4sZ0D2_HqvbSjJWLW8wZTRXN00&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1486066497769085&mt=1495473955&ip=2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe1f:fc40&ipbits=0&expire=1495488497&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,ttl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,sc,ei,driveid,mime,lmt&signature=8AFB0862FB9AB02C64544F9F462D7040303A1E04.80FD021C0481D93E50E842705E9B97F11617954A&key=ck2&??/Gemo.mp4
```

What weird is, that `api` param in the link. Is there an official api like this, that let me fetch the download links or the 'streaming' links for a video?

Comment: Example of my code: http://syriantc.com/abohani/apps/RamadanTime/DownloadGenerator.php?id=0B6F6PYlIBUC_MXhzM2MxcFhTNUk

Comment: Have you seen (and tested) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138204/4625829)?

Comment: @AL. Check the update in the answer.

Comment: You mean the comment? I saw it. But is it the same case for you though? I haven't tested it out myself. I would consider the comment, but there wasn't any upvote on it (which is usually the identifier if others experienced it too).

Comment: I want to get it in various qualities, not only one quality otherwise it would be easy to get a link. Im asking how did that api did it, it has an extra param and it works, no idea how.

Comment: I see. In any case, if you're looking for something official, AFAIK, there is no official Google Drive API for that at the moment. (*at the very least, not at the moment*)

Comment: I got my script from github 'vdo.php' and they're using the same but with a tiny modification that makes the link downloadable, so we have the same api but they fixed the 'you dont have permission' error.

Comment: I was able to check their api response but they encrypted the response and decrypting it from Android Side, link example 159.203.93.107/api/gdrive.php?url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6F6PYlIBUC_MXhzM2MxcFhTNUk/view&type=0 . I was able to locate the class that handles the decryption in their app, but they used Proguard on it which made it hard to dexjar-it.

Comment: Hi @Abo Hani you mentioned that you got the script from github 'vdo.php'. Can you show me the code/link? I might be able to help solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/hakan1983/bisil/blob/755b89a2154f2c129f5408e12ed76253a4d27fe1/src/vdo.php